# express PUT request is timing out

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, put

I am trying to update a file in my Mongo DB via a form using a PUT request in the browser and using Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate. It executes and the file updates in the database. However, the PUT request keeps executing indefinitely and is causing a timeout error.

I am new to Node/JS - and so apologies if this is a basic question.

```js
app.put('/essays/:id', async(req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const essay = await Essays.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {...req.body.essay });
  console.log("updated")
})
```

Browser:

```
<form action="/essays/<%=essay._id%>?_method=PUT" method="POST" id="myForm">
        <input type="hidden" id="essayBodyNew" name="essay[essayBody]" value=> </form>
```

Here is my console:

```
PUT /essays/600db52af8c50e195c159383?_method=PUT - - - - ms
```

It's also timing out when I make PUT requests on Postman.

Answer (score 1):

call `res.end('some message')` after `console` statement to close request

Comment: yeah, you need to response even no msg; tears

Comment: Of course you can as well just end the request with `res.end()` without sending a message, even better to set the status first like `res.status(200).end()`

Comment: So, I'm using a text editor based on EditorJS. Each time I make a change, it updates the file in my Mongo database via a PUT request. If I do res.end it takes me to a new page (blank page). I just want it to stay on the same page but stop trying to make the PUT request. The PUT request has actually worked (as the file has updated on my DB). This is what is confusing me. Is there a way to end it without taking me off the current page?

Comment: So, your problem is how to save EditorJS data but do not close editor. could you update your question with this part?

Comment: And using Ajax like that, basically it’s wrong way